# Error in firebase function that generates custom token

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to implement a Firebase function that generates a custom token for my app. But I keep getting the following error message :

> Error: could not handle the request

Or it ends up in timeout.

Do you have any idea of what could be wrong with my code hereafter ? I'm trying it with a 'test' uid.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

exports.customFunction = functions.https.onRequest((data, context) => {
  return admin.auth().createCustomToken('test')
  .then(customToken => {
      console.log(`The customToken is: ${customToken}`);
      return {
        status: 'success', 
        customToken: customToken
      };
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.error(`Something happened buddy: ${error}`)
      return {
        status: 'error'
      };
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Cloud Function is an [HTTPS one](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events). In order to terminate it you need to call `res.redirect()`, `res.send()`, or `res.end()` as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_express_request_and_response_objects).

In your code you actually return the Promises chain: this is the correct way to terminate Cloud function **triggered by background events** (which is not the case of an HTTPS Cloud Function which is triggered by a call to the URL it exposes).

So, the following changes should do the trick (untested):

```
exports.customFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res)(data, context) => {
  admin.auth().createCustomToken('test')  // No need to return 
  .then(customToken => {
      console.log(`The customToken is: ${customToken}`);
      response.status(200).send({
        status: 'success', 
        customToken: customToken
      });
  })
  .catch(error => {
      console.error(`Something happened buddy: ${error}`)
      response.status(500).send(error);
  });
});
```

---

Note that with an HTTPS Cloud Function, the objects you pass to the handler are not the Firebase `data` and [`context`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext) objects but the Express.js `request` and `response` objects.

So it is more clear to write

```
exports.customFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {...});
```

instead of

```
exports.customFunction = functions.https.onRequest((data, context) => {...});
```

Comment: I think OP has used `onRequest` instead of `onCall` here. the rest of the syntax and the use of `(data, context) => {}` implies that.

Comment: @samthecodingman you are most probably right! Let’s having Pierre confirming that.